# Run Time Error '1004': Select method of Range Class failed VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filldown formulas in a sheet. The code I am using is a recorded macro and it works fine until I connect it to a button. When I do so, it gives a

> "Run Time Error '1004': Select method of Range Class failed"

Here is the code and I can see nothing wrong with it. When I hit debug it highlights the second line

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Sheets("DB2 Totbel").Select

Range("B2:D2").Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:D15000"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("B2:D15000").Select
```

[picture of code in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiGEL.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity as to the parent worksheet of the B2:D2 and B2:D15000 ranges.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    With Sheets("DB2 Totbel")
        .Range("B2:D2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B2:D15000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        'uncomment these is you need to activate the DB2 Totbel worksheet
        'and select B2:D15000
        '.Activate
        '.Range("B2:D15000").Select
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Alternate with the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    With Sheets("DB2 Totbel")
        .Range("B2:D15000").FillDown
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Recorded macros are very verbose and make too much use of the `.Select` and `.Activate` commands. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I will also read the link on avoiding Select in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        With Sheets("DB2 Totbel")
            .Range("B2:D2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B2:D15000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.  yes corrected the error. But you already gave nice descriptive answer